# x264 Encoding use x264_picture_clean crash

Tags: ios, iphone, ffmpeg, x264, libx264

When I use iphone encoding CMSampleBufferRef To H264, it offen crash at `x264_picture_clean` I dont't know how to deal it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23wS6.png)

```
x264_picture_t* pPic_in;
```

here is my init about pPic_in

```
pPic_in = (x264_picture_t*)malloc(sizeof(x264_picture_t));
pPic_out = (x264_picture_t*)malloc(sizeof(x264_picture_t));

x264_picture_init(pPic_out);

x264_picture_init(pPic_in);
x264_picture_alloc(pPic_in, csp, pParam->i_width, pParam->i_height);

pPic_in->img.i_stride[0] = width;
pPic_in->img.i_stride[1] = width / 2;
pPic_in->img.i_stride[2] = width / 2;
pPic_in->img.i_plane = 3;
```

and i set data here

```
    picture_buf = yuv420_data;
    pPic_in->img.plane[0] = picture_buf;
    pPic_in->img.plane[1] = picture_buf + y_size;
    pPic_in->img.plane[2] = picture_buf + y_size*5/4;
```

it looks well , when i run it on my iphone,but sometimes it will crash at

```
x264_picture_clean
```

here is more detail abuot  pPic_in when crash occer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iooRr.png)

Thank u very much

Comment: Please remove the link to the image, and paste it as code placing a comment where the compiler it's signaling the error with it's error message.

Comment: Thread1:EXC_Bad_ACCESS(Code = 1 address = 0x107e3bff8)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this error happened because `x264_picture_clean` tries to free up the memory allocated to `img.plane[0]`:

```
x264_free( pic->img.plane[0] );
```

(see [`x264/common.c`](https://github.com/mirror/x264/blob/90a61ec76424778c050524f682a33f115024be96/common/common.c#L1183))

But `img.plane[0]` is now pointing to `yuv420_data`, instead of the memory internally allocated within `x264_picture_alloc`.

Since `x264_picture_clean` basically just free up the allocated memory pointed to by `img.plane[0]` and reinitialize `pPic_in`, it might be possible that you can skip calling `x264_picture_clean` without memory leak.  (If `yuv420_data` is dynamically allocated, you still need to deallocated it elsewhere).

BTW, `x264_picture_init` is called within `x264_picture_alloc`.